# How can I create my own site feature for office 365?

Tags: migration, feature, fab-40

I want to create my own site feature for 365.

I am doing migration process from MOSS 2007 to SP 2013 as well as Office 365.

In MOSS 2007 they used some FAB 40 template (Bug Database) this site template contain some feature like **Bug Tracking List Instances** and **Bug Tracking Modules**, so I want to bring this feature in Office 365.

So let me know how I can achieve it? What are the ways there is to do?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to recreate the complete template again or may be try to use 3rd party tool if they able to migrate it.
also check the below codeplex solution, i am sure will help you.

[Migrating the SharePoint 2007 “FAB 40” templates to SharePoint 2010](http://fab40.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Okay Thank you, If i would like to recreate then what can i do? give me any reference link to create feature for Office 365.